# Html.React doesn't render component on razor view page

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to render a react component on razor view page in .net core application. To do so I use "React.AspNet(4.1.1)" lib. In my Startup I added a react service

```
 services.AddReact(); 
 services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Also I added my component :

```
app.UseReact(configure => configure.AddScript("~/ClientApp/src/component.jsx"));
```

In my View I do:

```
@using React.AspNet
@Html.React("Hello", new { });
```

The component code:

```
 class Hello extends React.Component {
            render() {
            return(<h1>Hello React App</h1>);
        }
    }
```

As result where I go on this page I get blank page. If on my view there is some html before @Html.React, it renders correctly. I receive no errors.

Comment: I don't know your particular package, but you should need to mount your component into an existing element on the dom. Are you sure that your `@Html.React("Hello", new {});` is correct? Even if it is, `new {}` looks to be a empty component, which I'd expect to render empty.

Comment: I tried adding React.render method to my component. Also, new {}  is props for my component. And I have no props, just static element. I tried passing the props too, but it didn't help

Comment: I think I found your React [package](https://reactjs.net/). Looks like what you are missing is linking your script. You are using `configure.AddScript`, so this should be using [Server side rendering](https://reactjs.net/features/server-side-rendering.html). You need to actually include the bundle, as well as initialization scripts. The link I gave should give a tutorial. I don't really know this package (just React), so I'm going to bow out now. Good luck.